# my stub apk can not update new version from ggp

Tags: apk, google-play-games

I make a stub Apk that use the same sign and PackName as my app on googleplay and use the lower version.

When tap on stub apk, i make it just directly lead to the targeted app’s URL on Google Play. However, it is strange that the googleplay do not show the update button but the Open button. When i click open it will open this stub apk itself again.

Below its the sample code:

```
 try {    
                Intent playStore = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
                playStore.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
                sb = new StringBuilder();  
                sb.append("market://details?id=");  
                sb.append(packName);  
                playStore.setData(Uri.parse(sb.toString()));  
                startActivity(playStore);  
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {  
                Intent browserPlayStore = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
                browserPlayStore.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
                sb = new StringBuilder();  
                sb.append("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=");  
                sb.append(getPackageName());  
                browserPlayStore.setData(Uri.parse(sb.toString()));  
                startActivity(browserPlayStore);  
            }  
            finish();
```

Comment: You should post your code as text but not as images.

Comment: okay ,  i have post the code as text

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you 're not generating a signed apk. Generate a signed release apk & it should work fine.